# Detect low-quality circles/rings in image with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm trying to find all the cylindrical objects in an image which represents a map. Only their edges can be seen on the map and they can be very poor.
The aim is to find their centrum. All the object are circles with a constant radius in the real world. But their are not perfectly represented in the map.

Here is an example of image that I have to process :

[image: Map with circles to detect (surrounded in red)]

[image: Zoom 1]

[image: Zoom 2]

I'm using MATLAB 2009b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_detection_process) transform can be used to detect the shape of objects. You can use [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) or [OpenCv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html). Consider using the relevant [GPU OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html) if you are familiarized with gpu libs.

Good luck.